# HTTP Status Code Priority and Processing

Tags: http, http-status-codes, rfc

Let's say a web application gets the following request:

```
POST /some/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: <something>
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: pt
Content-Type: application/json
If-Match: "blabla"

Some body
```

- If the server doesn't support HTTP 1.1 *and* the endpoint `/some/endpoint` does not exist, the former problem should likely be checked first, and a 505 rather than 404 should be returned.
- If it just so happens that none of the endpoints of the server accept `POST` *and* the endpoint `/some/endpoint` doesn't exist, the latter should get priority, and 404 should be returned rather than 405.
- If the `Accept` can't be provided *and* the body can't be appropriately decoded/validated, probably 406 should take precedence over 400.

These are cases where intuition might suffice. But there are a myriad other ones where it is not clear which of two non-2XX status codes should be preferred/checked first. For example, should `Content-Type` (resulting in 415) or `Accept-Language` (406) be returned if both would fail? 415 or 412? And on it goes...

Much of the time errors are pairwise independent: if the aspect that is relevant to one error being thrown (such as a particular header value) is fixed, the success/error status of another will not be affected. In those cases, the wrong error "priority" is perhaps only a nuisance. But sometimes it may be the case that these errors are *not* independent: I might have a resources as HTML in Portuguese, but in JSON only in English (humour me), so that if a client expects me to prioritise `Accept-Language` over `Accept`, and I do the opposite, the result will be quite bad.

The question should be evident now: **are there any standards about which errors should be prioritised**?

I haven't come across any relevant RFCs, or even much serious and general discussion. I know of the [webmachine diagram](https://github.com/Webmachine/webmachine/wiki/Diagram), which sort of helps, but primarily just seems to describe a particular (well thought out) implementation rather than any standard.

Comment: You have not shown a valid `GET` request.  There is one too many spaces after the resource path, an HTTP 1.1 request *requires* a `Host` header (otherwise 400 **MUST** be returned), and a `GET` request cannot have a body at all.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: The specifications give the server ultimate authority in how it honors the request, even allowing the server to ignore the acceptable formats the client requests.  However, the specifications instruct the server to make a best effort and to respond in a way that best helps the client recover from errors.**

---

The specifications provide guidance, even if they don't (or can't) prioritize all possible error modes.

[RFC 2616 § 10.4.7 says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7):

> HTTP/1.1 servers are allowed to return responses which are
> not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the
> request. In some cases, this may even be preferable to sending a
> 406 response. User agents are encouraged to inspect the headers of
> an incoming response to determine if it is acceptable.

[RFC 7231 § 3 says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3):

> An origin server might be provided with, or be capable of generating,
> multiple representations that are each intended to reflect the
> current state of a target resource.  In such cases, some algorithm is
> used *by the origin server* to select one of those representations as
> most applicable to a given request, usually based on content
> negotiation.

[RFC 7231 § 3.4 says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4):

> Note that, in all cases, HTTP is not aware of the resource semantics.
> The consistency with which an origin server responds to requests ... is    determined entirely by whatever entity or algorithm selects
> or generates those responses.  *HTTP pays no attention to the man
> behind the curtain.*

[RFC 7231 § 3.3 says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.3):

> Response messages with an error status code
> usually contain a payload that represents the error condition, such
> that it describes the error state and what next steps are suggested
> for resolving it.

[RFC 2616 § 14.46 says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.46):

> The Warning general-header field is used to carry additional information about the status or transformation of a message which might not be reflected in the message. This information is typically used to warn about a possible lack of semantic transparency from caching operations or *transformations applied to the entity body of the message*.

---

(Emphases all mine.)

Section 3 of RFC 7231 gives the origin server ultimate authority to decide the appropriate response, even if that response is repugnant. Simultaneously, section 3 encourages the origin server to satisfy the request, or provide notice that it satisfied some of the request (`Vary`), or provide selectable options ("Passive negotiation").

Even though the server has ultimate authority, the specification makes clear to me that the responses should help the user resolve the problem.  In my mind, the best error code is the one that helps the user best fix the problem!

Considering your pair-wise examples:

- *"If the server doesn't support HTTP 1.1 and the endpoint /some/endpoint does not exist, the former problem should likely be checked first, and a 505 rather than 404 should be returned."*

No.  Per the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.6), an HTTP 1.1 client can `GET` from 1.0 server by protocol downgrade, so this kind of version negotiation is handled by the specification. Send a 404 (or a 301 if that's known) so the user can correct it.

- *"If it just so happens that none of the endpoints of the server accept POST and the endpoint /some/endpoint doesn't exist, the latter should get priority, and 404 should be returned rather than 405."*

Yes, 404.  If you're not getting to a resource, the method hardly matters.

- *"If the Accept can't be provided and the body can't be appropriately decoded/validated, probably 406 should take precedence over 400."*

Never send 400 when you know 406 applies. You're giving the client *less* information, which is *less* helpful. However, the origin server is free to ignore the `Accept` header per [RFC 7231 § 5.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2):

> If the [Accept] header field is
> present in a request and none of the available representations for
> the response have a media type that is listed as acceptable, the
> origin server can either honor the header field by sending a 406 (Not
> Acceptable) response or disregard the header field by treating the
> response as if it is not subject to content negotiation.

- *"I might have a resources as HTML in Portuguese, but in JSON only in English (humour me), so that if a client expects me to prioritise Accept-Language over Accept, and I do the opposite, the result will be quite bad."*

I disagree that the result will be bad. See [RFC 7231 § 5.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5):

> the origin server can either disregard the [Accept-Language] header field by treating the response as if it is not subject to content negotiation or honor the header field by sending a 406 (Not Acceptable) response.  However, the latter is not encouraged, as doing so can prevent users from accessing content that they might be able to use (with translation software, for example).

This pattern of specification language occurs more than once. "The server may disregard [whatever the client requested] by treating the response as if it's not subject to [this part of the specification], or the server may honor [the client request] and send [an applicable error code].  But, it's better to [send something intelligible] than only send [an inscrutable error code]."

At the end of the day, it's your API.  HTTP provides only a window into your semantics.  Document what you accept, how you respond, and with what.  Send intelligible responses (HATEOAS is good) and, when applicable, the most specific error codes available.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, you can’t expect this question to be answered “no,” even though that’s probably the correct answer.

So let me address a particular point of yours instead:

> I might have a resources as HTML in Portuguese, but in JSON only in English (humour me), so that if a client expects me to prioritise `Accept-Language` over `Accept`, and I do the opposite, the result will be quite bad.

In your example, you tell the server that Portuguese JSON is good, but all other combinations are *equally* bad. If that’s not the case, you can elaborate your preferences like this:

```
Accept: text/json
Accept-Language: pt, en;q=0.1
```

The server can then multiply your weights, getting 1×0.1=0.1 for English JSON and 0×1=0 for Portuguese HTML, and choosing the former.

(Sidenote 1: there is no `text/json` media type in [the registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). You probably want `application/json`.)

(Sidenote 2: [415 Unsupported Media Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13) is not a correct response code for the scenarios you mention. It concerns the request body. If you cannot honor the `Accept` header, you can respond with [406 Not Acceptable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6), just as with `Accept-Language`.)

Comment: I'd certainly accept "no" with some evidence supporting it. Even such evidence (e.g. some RFC that hints that priorities aren't officially legislated, or even just a blog post from someone who would know) I haven't been able to find, which is why I ask.