# Is an HTTP 405 (bad method) error a reliable indicator that a web resource exists?

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-405

I am trying to work out an efficient way of checking that a URL returns an existing resource/page.

Performing a `GET` and checking the response status = `200` works but is inefficient as it requests the whole page/resource.

Using a `HEAD` request method and checking the status response of that would seem ideal except that my target site does not support  `HEAD` requests (just `GET` and `POST`according to an options request. (It is not my site/sites that are being checked so enabling `HEAD` requests is not an option.)

Requesting a known good URL with the `HEAD` method results in a `405` error.

By experimenting I have found that if I request non-existing pages I get a return status code of `404` and various other errors also seem to make sense. I would prefer to confirm the existence of the page, though, rather than just assume existence by checking for a non-404 status code.

Can I, therefore, safely assume that if I get a `405` error that the page/resource exists?

This seems to be a question of response status precedence/priority.

Will a `404` error always take precedence over a `405` error or is this server or server configuration dependent?

If the order of precedence is defined, is this in an RFC or something?

([This question addresses a similar situation but for another specific situation)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30741120/2211491)